# How do I customize sample soft keyboard layout to fit tablet

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I downloaded the source of the sample soft keyboard and tried it out in my tablet..but it looks like this:

[image]

How do I customize the layout a little bit so that it will fit into the screen? I have been reading through http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html
but it does not help much with the layout customizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer: In the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: yep I found that too and it stretches the screen..Besides that I found drawing keyboard layout not very intuitive (you cannot see actually how it looks before you deploy it)